# Logging of small, low level objects

Tags: c++, logging

If we are in a C++ environment, especially one where we are fighting to keep resource usage low, how should we add logging to very low level objects which are prone to have issues with users of these objects?

Suppose we have a high level object `FileManager` that manages files. It has an internal map of `File` objects. It is easily possible for a user to enter an invalid file path when creating a `File` to manage. From the low level object, we can detect this error

```
bool File::CheckPath(std::string path){
   if(path[0] != "/"){
      std::cout << "missing / at start" << std::endl;
   }
   if(path[path.size() - 1] != "/"){
      std::cout << "missing / at end" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

But we want it to be part of our logging system and not `printf` or `cout`. Sure, we can detect errors from the `FileManager`, and `File` can return error codes, but we know in the future that other modules will want to be able to use `File` and don't want every single module to have to handle every error with a copy-paste log message. Since we can also manages 100s or 1000s of `File`s, we don't want a logging object to be within every `File` with unique log handles and so on.

How then do we provide a logging infrastructure to low level objects?

Comment: Are you files disk files or memory files?

Comment: Why don't you return error codes together with error messages? Or keep a static map of codes to messages (like errno). Side effects are bad, I don't recommend going down that road.

Comment: What do you mean by "side effects are bad" ?

Comment: Why would each `File` object need a logging object? (I don't know how your logging system works.)

Comment: @JaMiT The point is, it shouldn't - that would be wasteful. How then can we log errors from it without using `cout`

Comment: @terratermatwoa the code you've shown us has a side effect: it writes to cout. But you want to make it even worse, to implicitly refer to an arbitrary logger.

Comment: @terratermatwoa So why are you considering it? Adding a logging object to each low-level object is so far down my personal list of options that I wouldn't have bothered to mention it. What feature of your logging system led you to think of this option as the most likely option (until you realized there would be hundreds of low-level objects)?

Comment: Take a look at my example. If we have a failure at such a low level object, and we want to log it and carry on, how do we do that without adding logging to the object, or copy-pasting logging everywhere for consumers of the object? Maybe @freakish has the best idea so far.. or maybe it's time to use exceptions

Comment: @terratermatwoa Umm... off the top of my head there is: **1)** Use a global object (in a namespace), similar to how you used `std::cout` *in your example*. **2)** Use a `static` object member of the class. **3)** Use a `static` object *reference* member of the class. **4)** Use a member function of the class with the logging object as a `static` local variable. **5)** Use a global function (in a namespace). *Should I spend time thinking on how to extend the list? I'm hesitant to list "non-static member of the class" As number 6, as that seems too high up the list for something so wasteful.*

Comment: I can add that information as an answer, but I consider those options so obvious that I first wanted to know why you completely ignored them in favor of something so obviously wasteful.

Comment: @terratermatwoa With all due respect, the question is still rather unclear.  My guess is that you want any existing logging -- via `std::cout` etc. -- to be re-directed via some other system-wide logging facility.  Perhaps you could update your question with an example of the code you would *like* to be able to write (even if it doesn't compile).